# How to display the user's preferred language in a User profile page

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

In a Drupal 8/9 site, I can select the User's preferred language.

In the "*Manage form display*" page (for user's fields), there are two rows which are about language:

- `Language settings` (settings = --no settings available--)
- `Language code` (settings = "language select" as the only option)

**Question 1** : What do these two options produce?

In the "*Manage display*" page, I can display only one item about the language : `Language code`

As a result, if I visit my user profile page, I can see:

> **Language code**: French

But if I change my preferred language in my user edit profile page into Dutch, there is no effect in my "User view" page: it is always "French"

ok, I can preprocess something and adapt the twig template to display my preferred language but this is not the answer I would like to have.

**Question 2**: I would like to understand this behavior because, as always in Drupal, I am sure there is a good reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could answer myself to most of my questions:

1-The `Language code` field store the initial language of a user... it looks like it can't be changed after all. For my use case, it is an useless field.

2-The `Language settings` options display the **Preferred language** widget and the **Administration pages language** widget. I think that this last widget is there only if you check **Account administration pages language setting.** in `admin/config/regional/language/detection`

3-The most important part: How to display the preferred language of a user in the the display user page (`/user/xxx`)

You can do it with this hook:

```
function mymodule_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == "user") {
    $fields['preferred_langcode']->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
  }
}
```

I really don't know why it is not a default... (don't hesitate to add any information on this point)